# StackOverflow error when trying to repeatedly check a variable

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Hey before I start I want to let everyone know I'm not only new to this forum but Unity and C# itself so I apologize if there is an easy solution or other silly mistakes.

Alright so basically what I am trying to do is switch the gravity of my player when they hit space, to achieve this I am checking the players transform.position.y and seeing if it is at it's designated height and if it's not I add force.

The area of code:

```
private void ChangeGravity()
    {
            if (rb.position.y >= 10f)
            {
                SAF = false;
                rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;  
            }
            else
            {
                rb.AddForce(0, VerticalForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
                ChangeGravity();
            }
    }
```

For clarification SAF is a precautionary measure so that the player can't spam the space button.
Also VerticalForce = 2f and through my testing I have determined that it is possible for the if statement to be true (this test was by setting the y to 10)

Now here's the error:

```
StackOverflowException
UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3 force, ForceMode mode)
UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (Single x, Single y, Single z) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Dynamics/ScriptBindings/Dynamics.bindings.cs:171)
PlayerMovement.ChangeGravity () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:21)
PlayerMovement.ChangeGravity () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:22)
(The final line repeats a bunch but I cut that out)
```

The Entire Script: [The Script](https://pastebin.com/Vw7b5FkV)

---

**EDIT**

I finally found a very helpful tutorial that i wouldnt have found without you guys on how to reverse gravity of an object, this makes this question obsolete, thank you for your time i'm sorry i didn't find this before making the question.

Comment: you have ChangeGravity(); calling itself.....so a stackoverflow is not unexpected.

Comment: Yes, like I said I  am running the function repeatedly till the statement it true

Comment: There is no question here: you know you are recursively calling ChnageGravity() but you find it surprising it overflows?

Comment: But eventuley it shouldn't have to call itself because the statement above will be true

Comment: well stacks aren't infinite! Otherwise they would never overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method does not return, it calls itself which in turn calls itself again.

Since calling a function allocates some memory on the thread’s stack, the stack is soon overflowed since it has a space limit of a few MegaBytes.

Call this method in while loop, break the loop when the condition is met. So in each iteration of the loop the method is returned and the call stack won’t grow.

```
   while (true)
   {
        if (rb.position.y >= 10f)
        {
            SAF = false;
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;  
            break; //break the loop since condition is met
        }
        else
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, VerticalForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            continue; //the condition is not met, so the loop goes on
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes with my limited knowledge of while loops I tried and failed at something like this, if you could provide an example that would be great

Comment: The stackoverflow exception should have gone since the method is not recursive now, right?

Comment: this is just a different version of the same recursive method. if the condition is not met it will go infinite instead of throwing stack overflow.

Comment: And we are back to square one, this loop is actually infinite where before mine wasn't, to make sure of this i reduced the number to if 2 which means if any force is applied it will break and it didnt.

Comment: @SelmanGenç the difference is the call stack won’t grow. It can iterate forever without having the stack overflow. In your version since the method calls itself recursively, it will hit the stackoverflow exception after a few dozen times (as usually observed in debugger) if the condition is not met.

Comment: How to break out of the infinite loop is another question.

Comment: "Your method does not return, it calls itself which in turn calls itself again." - This is a true but misleading statements. 1) It does call itself 2) *Given an unbound depth* it would produce the same result as the correction - or both hang. So *if* that code "fixes" the problem is merely in the *depth* of recursion (causing an SOE), not that a the terminal case is not reached or "does not return [at all]" or "calls itself again" (as limited recursion is okay).

Comment: As stated in the now-deleted answer, `if (d) { a; return } else { b }` won't "prevent" execution of b any more than `if (d) { a } else { b }` -- that is, return is irrelevant to termination of a method that is only recursive on the 'else' path.

Comment: Yes I think I am over simplifying the situation by stating recursive leads to overflow, limited recursion as in “Fibonacci series” is OK. Controlling the depth of recursion is the key.